# How to catch Checkbox check/uncheck event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have list of check box. Some of them are checked while some are unchecked. I need to enable the submit either on check/uncheck of the check box. All the check box has same css class. Any suggestion on which jquery event I should write my code?

Comment: check or uncheck of a single checkbox ? all checkboxes ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

You can find a working example here:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: I don't see alert firing !

Comment: @liliput: I've added a working example to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help to you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#submit_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#submit_btn").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have markup like this

```
  <input type="checkbox" checked class="a" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="a" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked class="a" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="a" />

  <input type="submit" disabled id="btnSubmit"  />
```

The below code will listen to the `change` event, and enable the input button.

```
$(function(){

  $("input[type='checkbox'].a").change(function(){

    $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
  });        

})
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qedopameko/edit?html,js,output) is a working sample

Comment: I tried implementing the same but It did not work, I don't see debugger going in the block anytime.

Comment: What did not work ? Did you see the WORKING JSBIN i posted ? compare it with your code. Also make sure you do not have any js errors in your page.